# Scrolling vertically a d3 chart in scroll container

Tags: d3.js, scroll, mousewheel

I have created a little snippet to simplify my problem:
https://jsfiddle.net/2k2bv159/

```
var svg = d3.select("#chart")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", "100%")
  .attr("height", "100%")
  .call(d3.zoom().on("zoom", function () {
    if (d3.event.sourceEvent.ctrlKey) {
      svg.attr("transform", d3.event.transform);
    }
}))
.append("g");

svg.append("circle")
  .attr("cx", document.body.clientWidth / 2)
  .attr("cy", document.body.clientHeight / 2)
  .attr("r", 50)
  .style("fill", "#B8DEE6")
```

I have a zoomable d3-chart inside a scroll container. I would like to use the mouse wheel for scrolling instead of zooming.
Zoom should happen on ctrl+wheel.

How could I config the chart, so I don't have to manually scroll via 'jQuery.scroll()'? Is there an easy way?

Kind regards

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [filter](https://github.com/d3/d3-zoom#zoom_filter) method:

```
var zoom = d3.zoom()
  .on("zoom", function () {
    svg.attr("transform", d3.event.transform);       
  })
  .filter(function(){
    return d3.event.ctrlKey;
  });
```